# Пропускает один ввод char

Tags: c, char, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
    char a,b;
    scanf("%c", &a);
    scanf("%c", &b);
    printf("%c %c", a, b);
return 0;
}
```

Вот такой код делал для теста, считывает только а и выводит только а. А про b забывает

Comment: Так что сделать то надо?

Comment: Сделать так, что бы считывало b тоже

Comment: Так а что именно вы вводили? Буквально, какие клавиши нажимали?

Comment: После запуска пишу a и enter. Все, конец программы

Comment: А не 'энтер' ли вводится (и выводится) в Вашу `b`? ;-) Попробуйте `b` вывести как целое число: `printf("%c %d", a, (int)b);` и все увидите...

Comment: Ну так "enter" - это тоже символ. Именно он и попадает в ваше `b`. Поставьте пробелы перед `%c` в строках формата `scanf`: `scanf(" %c", &a);`.